# Unable to spread state in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was building a form, for which I need to store some of the form data in a global store as the form has multiple steps.

However, I have been struggling with a few things, I'm using Zustand and I have the following code currently in my store.js

```
 formState: [],
   
    addToForm: (data) => {
        set(state => ({
            data: [...state.formState, data]
        }));
    }
```

Then in my component, I call this hook by using `addToForm(formState.education)` but I encounter the following error -

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

The formData.education object looks like this :

```
Array [
  Object {
    "country": "UK",
    "degree": "Bsc",
    "university": "Uni of Leeds",
    "year": 1971,
  },
]
```

I'm trying to make it so the `formState` state object can hold multiple items thats why I have used the spread method but however, this doesn't seem to work so far.

Comment: Hey, @kentrell Jr. Are you using a functional component?

Comment: please show me show code

Comment: please check this code it may help you [useReducer pattern implementation][1]
  [1]: https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/ecommerce-site/blob/master/frontend/components/ProductForm.js

Comment: What does `state.formState` contain when the error occurs? It's apparently not something you can iterate over.

Comment: @zainuldin yes I'm using functional components, its basically just an `onPress` event handler that calls the `addToForm` hook inside my functional component, I will edit the post to add that function now,

@jperl So `formState` is initially just an empty array but that is the store in which I'm trying to store all the `formData.education` objects.

Comment: simply do 
`const [state , setState] = useState ([])
 function Update (data) { setState ([...state , data]) }
 ` USAGE : setState (2)